# How to use FileWatcher to run script in WebStorm

Tags: macos, zsh, webstorm, file-watcher

I have a script in `.restart` file and I'd like to run it on save in WebStorm. I'm trying to use file watcher for that but all the time I'm getting error:

```
/bin/zsh $HOME$/.restart
/bin/zsh: can't open input file: $HOME$/.restart
```

My configuration of FileWatcher:

```
Program: zsh
Arguments: $HOME$/.restart
```

I tried many different combinations of slashes and variables both from WebStorm and global env variables. Non of them seems to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `$HOME$` here? I do not see such a macro in the available macro list for File Watchers... It must be the OS/shell provided variable then?.. File Watcher executes the command directly (creates the process with passed parameters). In this case that `$HOME$` will be passed as is (unless `zsh` can parse it in own parameters list).

Comment: It's custom macro I made, I just pasted one of my trials, I was putting there many things along with webstorm default macros

Answer (score 0):

Just put absolute path to the file in the argument